# How to add external library dependency to libgdx project?

Tags: libgdx

I am trying to add a simple library like json.org to my libgdx project. The dependencies were properly configured in the gradle file. The project is not compiling any longer. I think the problem is because the GWT compiler is not able to find the source code. Did this happen to someone else before? Any possible solution?
Thanks.

Comment: When using intelliJ you alsohave a gradle-tab on the right hand sidein the IDE, clicking on the gradle-tab will show you a refresh-button on the upper-left corner in this tab. This will refresh your whole project including all its dependencies

Answer (score 1):

What errors are you getting ?

Try to issue the command from the command line:

```
gradlew --refresh-dependencies
```

Got this one from the Universal [Tween Engine installation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Universal-Tween-Engine) page, probably can help your case. From the page text:

> And most importantly you now need to refresh your project dependencies through your IDE or by running the following command from your project directory:

Comment: I think that's not really solving the issue. I did refresh the dependencies within eclipse and that is working, but then when compiling I get the following. Note that I include a gradle dependency to org.json:

Loading inherited module 'com.mygdx.game.GdxDefinition'
   Loading inherited module 'org.json'
      [ERROR] Unable to find 'org/json.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
   [ERROR] Line 5: Unexpected exception while processing element 'inherits'
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log...)