# How can I bring Google play services into my libGDX Gradle project?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, libgdx

After adding Google Play Services to integrate Google ads into my libGDX project in Eclipse, I can no longer use Gradle to build my Android project.

I know that's because I need to tell Gradle about the new Google Play project dependency so I added compile `com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89` to the dependencies section of the `:android project` however it complains that it could not find `com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0`.

I guess that means I need to somehow tell Gradle this new dependency depends on another dependency?

Everything works fine in Eclipse so the dependency of my Google Play project in Eclipse is for sure golden, I just need to make Gradle the same way. Do I need to declare the Google play project as another Gradle project and make a `build.gradle` file for it? I don't think I should be touching the Google Play project contents at all.

Comment: You should post the exact error.

Comment: Please have a look at this: [How to add external library dependency to libgdx project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26340456/how-to-add-external-library-dependency-to-libgdx-project/26342149#26342149) maybe that is related to your situation.

Comment: I've used that guide to add the Tween engine. That is a little different because I don't have to import the Tween engine into my eclipse workspace. It is simply an external dependency.

Answer (score 0):

If you have downloaded the tools and google reprositories using the Android SDK Manager (1st thing to check), check if your build.gradle files do not need to be updated (what libGDX version are you currently using?). 
I had the same problem and solved it by replacing my Android's module build.gradle file by a brand new.

To do so, use the last ligdx setup ui (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-Setup-Gradle) to create a fresh project then compare/replace gradle files.

Answer (score 0):

Under your android module there's a build.gradle file. Add the following:

```
dependencies {
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'
}
```

Check for the latest version of Google Play Services and update your version number accordingly.